# Stop Bootstrap Navbar Hamburger Stacking With Branding

Tags: html, css

[image]

The picture demonstrates this well. When resizing the browser the hamburger stacks, then (still being stacked) the logo resizes via 'max-width: 100%'. For some reason I can't figure out how to disable stacking and force the logo to resize earlier. Here is the plain code with attempted fixes erased.

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-lg dropShad noMar">

 <div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="navbar-header">

   <a class="navbar-brand noPad" href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" style="width: 355px; max-width: 100%;" /></a>

   <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed marBot18" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#corbex-navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false">

    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>

   </button>

 </div>

 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="corbex-navbar-collapse">

  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

   <li class="active"><a href="index.html"><b>Home</b><span class="sr-only">(current)></span></a></li>

   <li><a href="location.html"><b>Location</b></a></li>

   <li><a href="contactUs.html"><b>Contact Us</b></a></li>

  </ul>

 </div>

    </div>

</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the natural behavior of these 2 blocks to stack when single line space is not sufficient.

Try give the brand logo percentage width in certain viewport, like 60% for brand logo and 40% for hamburger to keep them same line.